# have a function in Scheme return value (or do something else) and call itself

Tags: scheme

I would like to have two expressions evaluated in function body. How would I go about it?

Given the following:

```
(define (f)
  ((+ 2 2) (+ 4 4)))
```

I would like both to have 2+2 and 4 + 4 evaluated (obviously the above doesn't work).

Basically, if I understand it correctly, in a spot where I can get a single thing done, I would like to have two things done. For example instead of calling just one function as a consequent in the if expression, I'd like to call two functions. Or ideally return a value and have the function call itself.

I am not sure if this  makes sense but conceptually having such a mechanism seems plausible.

Comment: Why do you want `(2 + 2)` (or rather `(+ 2 2)`, I assume) to be evaluated? It doesn't have any side-effects, so evaluating it without using the result wouldn't serve any purpose as far as I can tell.

Comment: "Or ideally return a value and have the function call itself" - That's called _recursion_, are you asking about recursive procedures? the question is a bit confusing, it's not clear what the problem is

Comment: Yes, apologies for not being precise. Thank you very much for all the great answers to my imperfect questions! I definitely feel educated now :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The body of a procedure evaluates from top-to-bottom, no matter how many expressions are at the beginning, only the value of the last one is returned. For instance, if we write this:

```
(define (f)
  (+ 2 2)  ; evaluates to 4, but we don't do anything with it, so it's lost
  (+ 4 4)) ; evaluates to 8, this is the returned value
```

... When we call `(f)` the returned value is `8`, the first expression's value is lost. Perhaps you meant to say, that you want multiple values returned? this is possible depending on the interpreter, for instance in Racket:

```
(define (f)
  (values (+ 2 2) (+ 4 4)))

(f)
=> 4
   8
```

Now `(f)` returns *two* values, if we are going to use them, we need special forms to "capture" the multiple returned values. In this example, I'll use `let-values`:

```
(let-values (((x y) (f))) ; 4 is bound to x, 8 is bound to y
  (+ x y))
=> 12
```

Another interpretation of your question, regarding the use of an `if` expression: if you need to write more than one expression inside an `if`, then you have to pack all the expressions inside a `begin` form (by the way: the body of a procedure is implicitly inside a `begin`).

But *again*, even tough all the expressions are executed in sequence, only the value of the last one is returned as a result - so all the expressions in the middle should be executed only for the effect, not for the value. For example:

```
(if (= 1 1)    ; condition is true
    (begin     ; execute a sequence of expressions
      (+ 2 2)  ; evaluates to 4, but the value is lost
      (+ 4 4)) ; evaluates to 8, this is the returned value
    (begin
      (+ 1 1)
      (+ 3 3)))
=> 8
```

Of course, in the above example it'd be simpler to just use a `cond`, which has an implicit `begin`. This is equivalent to the previous snippet:

```
(cond
  ((= 1 1)   ; condition is true, implicit `begin`
   (+ 2 2)   ; evaluates to 4, but the value is lost
   (+ 4 4))  ; evaluates to 8, this is the returned value
  (else
   (+ 1 1)
   (+ 3 3)))
=> 8
```

Comment: Very nice, didn't know about the `values` construct.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what you mean, you simply call the functions one after another:

```
(define (f)
  (display "calling-function-1")
  (newline)
  (display "calling-function-2"))
```

Output:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.3.5 [3m].
Language: SICP (PLaneT 1.17); memory limit: 128 MB.
> (f)
calling-function-1
calling-function-2
```

If you did this with addition:

```
(define (f)
  (+ 2 2) (+ 4 4))
```

It would still work correctly, and just return the last value:

```
Welcome to DrRacket, version 5.3.5 [3m].
Language: SICP (PLaneT 1.17); memory limit: 128 MB.
> (f)
8
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a great answer to my imperfect question :) I accepted the one above due to a slightly deeper treatment but I wished I could accept both since both answer my question... Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to evaluate a sequence of expressions in a place where only a single one is allowed (i.e. an `if` consequence), you need to use `begin`. This isn't the case for the body of a `define`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Was not aware that define was unique in this respect. Things make much more sense now.

Comment: @dreamwalker: Actually, `define` is not the only operator to support a sequence of expressions. Just look out in the relevant standard document (i.e. R5RS) for parameters designated by `<body>` rather than anything else.